# Need to group only the name in the query, but access considers all the other columns

Tags: vba, ms-access

I only need to group by name but the GROUP BY does not work with access even after using HAVING. Even if I try to GROUP BY only one field, the group does not happen.

The error with this grouping is, it does not render complete output in the excel file. For an example: If the table contains 20 rows with tax amount, the output renders only 10 rows with incomplete calculation. Could you please help with the correct query?

```
Dim Db, s, rs As Object, xlApp As Object, wb As Object, sql As String, i As Integer
Set Db = CurrentDb

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True

For Each s In Array("1025", "1028", "1033")
    
  sql = ("SELECT t.invno, t.vendorid, t.Subsidiary, t.InvDate, t.InvTaxAmt, t.[CurrencyCode], t.[Reference #], t.[Timesheet Date]," & _
  "t.[Center ID], t.Location, t.[Project ID], t.[Amount (Line/Expense)], t.[Item Code], t.[Tax Amount (Line/Expense)]," & _
  "t.[Gross Amount (Line/Expense)], t.[Quantity (Line/Item)], t.[Description (Line/Item)], t.[Rate (Line/Item)], t.[Approver Time Stamp]," & _
  "t.[Supplier Name], t.[Invoice Submit Date], t.[Worker ID], t.[Actual UOM], t.[Approver Username]" _
    & "FROM tbl_result where t.[Subsidiary]= '" & s & "'" _
    & "GROUP BY t.invno, t.vendorid, t.Subsidiary, t.InvDate, t.InvTaxAmt, t.[CurrencyCode], t.[Reference #], t.[Timesheet Date]," & _
  "t.[Center ID], t.Location, t.[Project ID], t.[Amount (Line/Expense)], t.[Item Code], t.[Tax Amount (Line/Expense)]," & _
  "t.[Gross Amount (Line/Expense)], t.[Quantity (Line/Item)], t.[Description (Line/Item)], t.[Rate (Line/Item)], t.[Approver Time Stamp]," & _
  "t.[Supplier Name], t.[Invoice Submit Date], t.[Worker ID], t.[Actual UOM], t.[Approver Username]")

       
    Set rs = Db.OpenRecordset(sql)
   
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(CurrentProject.Path & "\Temp" & s & ".xlsx")
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        rs.MoveLast
        Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
        rs.MoveFirst
    End If
    
    i = 3 ' start of the cell
    While Not rs.EOF
        Range("B" & i) = rs![invno]
        Range("C" & i) = rs![vendorid]
        Range("D" & i) = rs![Subsidiary]
        Range("E" & i) = rs![InvDate]
        Range("F" & i) = rs![InvTaxAmt]
        Range("G" & i) = rs![CurrencyCode]
        Range("H" & i) = rs![Reference #]
        Range("I" & i) = rs![Timesheet Date]
        Range("J" & i) = rs![Center ID]
        Range("K" & i) = rs![Location]
        Range("L" & i) = rs![Project ID]
        Range("M" & i) = rs![Amount (Line/Expense)]
        Range("N" & i) = rs![Item Code]
        Range("O" & i) = rs![Tax Amount (Line/Expense)]
        Range("P" & i) = rs![Gross Amount (Line/Expense)]
        Range("Q" & i) = rs![Quantity (Line/Item)]
        Range("R" & i) = rs![Description (Line/Item)]
        Range("S" & i) = rs![Rate (Line/Item)]
        Range("T" & i) = rs![Approver Time Stamp]
        Range("U" & i) = rs![Supplier Name]
        Range("V" & i) = rs![Invoice Submit Date]
        Range("W" & i) = rs![Worker ID]
        Range("X" & i) = rs![Actual UOM]
        Range("Y" & i) = rs![Approver Username]
        
        
        i = i + 1 'Increment the cell position.
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
          
           'Save as PDF
SaveInvoice:
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs CurrentProject.Path & "\Sub_" & s & ".xlsx"
           wb.Close False
        rs.Close
     Next s
     xlApp.Quit
MsgBox "Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: We don't know what the "correct query" could be, as we don't know about neither input nor requested output. But an aggregating query must either group by a field or sum/count,min/max its values.

Comment: The select query is correct. I only need the grouping done according to the name t.[Description (Line/Item)]

Comment: If you don't include all fields in GROUP BY, they must either be used in an aggregate calc (SUM, AVG, COUNT, FIRST, MAX, etc) or WHERE clause. Since there is no aggregate calculating, perhaps you really mean ORDER BY. Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables.

Comment: If GROUP BY is reducing number of records, then there must be duplicate records. Primary purpose of GROUP BY is to AGGREGATE data, not order records, although they will sort. What calculation is 'incorrect'? I don't see any calculation in that query. Why export to Excel?